# What is the best BlazeDS polling method for an low bandwidth network?

Tags: blazeds, bandwidth, polling, long-polling

I am wondering BlazeDS polling configuration, simple or long polling, is the best for a low bandwidth network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP Streaming should use the least amount of bandwidth and have the lowest latency.  But make sure you configure a fail-over in case the connection can't be made.

Answer (score 0):

As James said, HTTP streaming. If you cannot do it (for example if you are not allowed to keep open connection for more than 20 seconds) I would stick with long polling over the simple one.